# Refreshing jQuery variable as selector vs re-using selector performance

Tags: jquery, performance

I'm wondering if there is any difference in performance between refreshing a jQuery variable as a selector [like this](http://gistflow.com/posts/342-how-refresh-a-stored-jquery-selector-variable) and just using the selector twice.

Comment: None that you'll ever notice ?

Comment: Give it a try - For example, if you intend to repeat the calls, put both of them into a loop, for a large number of iterations, see if there's any large difference.

Comment: I'd suggest not using the .selector property. http://api.jquery.com/selector/. Instead, build the plugin on `$` directly such as `$.myplugin = function (selector,options){...` so that you have access to the selector in a way that isn't going to go away in future versions of jQuery.

Comment: isn't `.selector` already deprecated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everyone's answer so far is true:

1. The difference is negligible (see next point for proof)
2. You can put them in a loop and try (http://jsperf.com/selector-refresh-vs-new-selector)
3. In both cases the selector string is the same
4. The selector property is deprecated

Comment: Thank you, that jsperf link was very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

In the link you provided there is no functional difference.  The only change is in the source of the selector string (hard-coded as opposed to derived from a property).  In both cases the same selector string is run through jQuery.